# ERROR [+7050] HMError: HMM Def Error: GetToken: Symbol expected at line 1/col 2/char 1 in ./data/test/feature/T0011.mfc

Tags: speech-recognition, htk

```
HMM Def Error: GetToken: Symbol expected at line 1/col 2/char 1 in ./data/test/feature/T0011.mfc
  ERROR [+7050]  HMError:
HMM Def Error: LoadHMMSet: GetToken failed at line 1/col 0/char -1 in ./data/test/feature/T0011.mfc
  ERROR [+7050]  HMError:
  ERROR [+3228]  Initialise: LoadHMMSet failed
 FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HVite
```

```
I am using HTK3.4.1 to build the voice dialing system in HTK book. After repairing the mute model, I want to test the accuracy first. I executed this command：
    HVite -H ./hmms/hmm17/macros -H ./hmms/hmm17/hmmdefs -S test.scp -l * -i ./results/recout_step7.mlf -w wdnet -p 0.0 -s 5.0 ./dict/dict1 ./lists/monophones1

and the following error occurred：
```

HMM Def Error: GetToken: Symbol expected at line 1/col 2/char 1 in ./data/test/feature/T0011.mfc
ERROR [+7050]  HMError:
HMM Def Error: LoadHMMSet: GetToken failed at line 1/col 0/char -1 in ./data/test/feature/T0011.mfc
ERROR [+7050]  HMError:
ERROR [+3228]  Initialise: LoadHMMSet failed
FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HVite

Can someone tell me how to deal with this error? I will be very grateful!